# React does not change state after updating state in usestate hook (in custom function form)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am using usestate hook in react 16.10.2, but after updating initial state using custom function in usetate hook, react does not trigger a re-render(OtherComponent is not rendered), Here is my react component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import OtherComponent from "./OtherComponent";

function Component(props) {

   const [render, setRender] = useState({0:false, 1:false});
   const display_data = (index) => {
      setRender((prevState) => {
         prevState[index] = !prevState[index];
         return prevState;
      });
   };

   return (
      <>
         {{custom_json_array}.map((record, index) => {
            return (
                  <div>{teacher_render[index] ? 'true' : 'false'}</div>
                  <button onClick={() => display_data(index)}>change state</button>
                  {render[index] ? <OtherComponent /> : ''}
               </div>)
         })}
      </>
   );

}
```

But strange thing is if I return {...prevState} from hook updater function, everything is normal and re-render is triggerd!
I am totally confused, why react behaves like this?!

Comment: What is `{custom_json_array}` as it looks like an object in your example

Comment: I assume `display_data ` and `display_teacher_data` are meant to be the same

Comment: that was a typing mistake, you are right dude

Comment: custom_json_array is a custom json array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume the problem is that you are mutating `render`?

```js
<button 
  onClick={() => setRender({ ...render, [index]: !render[index] })}
>
  change state
</button>
```

In this example, click on the names to see the custom component and click again to hide

https://codesandbox.io/s/dark-wind-3310q

```js
const CustomComponent = () => (
  <div style={{ marginLeft: 10, background: "red" }}>I'm Selected!</div>
);

function App() {
  const [people] = useState([
    { id: 0, name: "Mario" },
    { id: 1, name: "Luigi" },
    { id: 2, name: "Peach" }
  ]);

  const [selected, setSelected] = useState({});

  return (
    <div>
      {people.map(({ id, name }) => (
        <div
          style={{ display: "flex", cursor: "pointer" }}
          key={id}
          onClick={() => setSelected({ ...selected, [id]: !selected[id] })}
        >
          {name}
          {selected[id] && <CustomComponent />}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is a simplified example of the erroneous code you posted, to show no update occurring:

https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-williamson-22fgs

```js
function App() {
  const [obj, setObj] = useState({ name: "Mario" });
  const change = () => {
    // The following commented code will display no change
    // obj.name = "Peach";
    // setObj(obj);
    setObj({ ...obj, name: "Peach" });
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>{obj.name}</div>
      <button onClick={change}>Change!</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: tnx, but why I should mutate render like you? what is problem in my method??

Comment: Otherwise you could still be using the same object if a re-render was not triggered by that object being updated

Comment: See updated answer with link https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-williamson-22fgs

Comment: thx for attention, but I modified prevState inside the function, why this generate error?

Comment: Because you are still using the same object. `prevState` in your example is still the same object. You should create a new object with the changed data

Comment: The erroneous example seems to work (it updates).
I have similar code that doesn't update though..

Answer (score 0):

Your onclick handler is called `display_teacher_data` in the markup but `display_data` in the component. Set them to be the same so the state changes.

Comment: that was a typing mistake dude